# monitor connections to my server

Tags: linux, security, debian

Is there a way I can monitor connections that are attempted/made to my linux server? I'm running Debian Lenny.

Comment: need more info on what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also set up iptables to log when a TCP connection is started or attempted.  UDP is trickier, since there's no real "start" or "stop" for UDP, just packets.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't they logged into /var/log/messages?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you specifically want to do;  What type of monitoring?  Full content of the connections or just basic session information?  In realtime or do you want to log to a file for later analysis?

Something like TCPDump would be a great real-time monitor, and you can also save to a pcap file for later analysis.

-Josh

Answer (score 1):

I find the **iptstate** tool really useful to monitor iptables entries in real time. On Fedora it is a *yum install iptstate* so I imagine in Debian you can install via *apt-get*.

As already mentioned, for very detailed analysis, *tcpdump* is awesome (or alternatively *Wireshark*).

Not sure about Debian, but on Fedora you need to adjust the settings in **/etc/rsyslog.conf** to configure verbose firewall logs in syslog or a custom log file.

For regular reports, Logwatch is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try scheduling command `ss -s` to check number of connections made on your server at some convenient interval using [cron tab](http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/).

Or there is a free service, [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) which you can use to schedule commands and see output online.